# How to mathematically represent a closed region in a formal way?

Tags: general-topology

I am considering how to represent the following region mathematically.

Given random numbers $\xi_i,i=1,...,n,n \rightarrow  \infty $ which are following a particular distribution; and a constant $b$, I want to represent the closed region which covers all possible numbers $b+\xi_i$. My initial attempt is as follows:

$$B=\{\cup_{\forall \xi_i} (b+\xi_i)\}.$$

But my tutor believes this representation stands for a point set instead of a region.

Comment: Are you wanting to construct an expression for the distribution for numbers of the form $b+\xi_i$ for given fixed $b$?

Comment: In my case, the constant $b$ is fixed.

Comment: That's what I thought, but is what you want to represent the probability distribution, or just a particular set of (random) numbers.

Comment: That depends on the underlying distribution. If the distribution is continuous,  the region should be continuous. Otherwise, it is a set of numbers.

Comment: A region is (just) a set, set's (generally) don't have a notion of continuity. Functions have a notion of continuity. Is $B$ supposed to just be a set of (random) numbers, or a PDF (probability density function).

Comment: Err.... I tend to write $B$ by using a PDF.

Comment: So $B$ is intended to be a probability density function (PDF) then, correct?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation $A+B$ is customary to express the set $\{a+b:a\in A,b\in B\}$. (Of course, $A$ and $B$ must be subsets contained in some set where $+$ is defined).

Likewise, $a+B$ is commonly defined as $\{a+b:b\in B\}$.

So I'd write the set you want this way:

$$b+\{\xi_i:1\le i\le n\}$$

But perhaps you should define this notation previously.

I'm not sure what you mean with 'closed region that covers'. If you mean the topological closure (given the tag, this seems probable), simply put a bar over it.

Answer (score 1):

We will denote the PDF from which the $\xi_i$'s are derived by $\Xi(x)$. Then the numbers of the form $b+\xi_i$ have PDF $B(x)=\Xi(x-b)$. The intuition here is that all the $-b$ part does is translate the PDF horizontally by $b$ units, the distribution is otherwise the same.

Comment: 1) Shouldn't it rather be $B(x)=\Xi(x-b)$? 2) I seems to me this does not answer the question.

Comment: The problem statement explicitly asks for numbers $b+\xi_i$ and the $b$ is a single fixed constant, and in no way influences how the $\xi_i$'s are generated from the PDF $\Xi(x)$

Comment: If you add a non-zero constant to a PDF, you do not get another PDF.

Comment: I see the problem now, I basically translated along the wrong axis. Fixing...